# Loop con regresiones en R

Tags: r, rstudio, machine-learning

Tengo que estimar un modelo lineal simple con una variable dependiente que es un índice (ir) y una variable independiente que son precipitaciones de una estación meteorológica. En total son 18 estaciones y tengo que obtener los r cuadrado de cada una de esas regresiones. 
La pregunta entonces es, ¿cómo puedo estimar todas esas regresiones dejando fija la variable dependiente y cambiando sólo la independiente (las estaciones) ?
Lo que se me ocurre es un for que recorra un array que contenga los nombres de las estaciones.

```
df <- data.frame(data)

vec <- data.frame(colnames(df))

for (i in vec) {

    random_model = lm(data = df, formula = ir ~ i )
    summary(random_model)
}
```

pero  me arroja un error :

```
> for (i in vec) {
+   
+     random_model = lm(data = df, formula = ir ~ i )
+     summary(random_model)
+ }
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ir ~ i, data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'i')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los bucles dan mucho trabajo en R y hay una alternativa mucho mejor: las funciones funcionales o bucles implícitos. En este caso si solo te interesan los r² podrías usar `sapply()` y una función anónima.

1. Como un data.frame es una lista (especial, pero una lista) `sapply()` se va a encargar de pasar la función por cada columna/elemento de la lista.
2. Como necesito indicar a cada variable en la llamada a la función (en este caso, indicar cuál es la variable independiente en cada modelo) declaro una función anónima y llamo `x` a elemento sobre el que estoy iterando. De este modo `sapply()` se encargará de ajustar un modelo lineal en el que la dependiente siempre es `mtcars$mpg` y la independiente será, en cada "turno", cada columna del data.frame. Uso el "comodín" x para indicarlo en la llamada.
3. Como te interesa el r² haces el sumario de cada modelo. El sumario también es una lista nombrada, así que puedes usar `$` para acceder a algún valor de la lista. En este caso la r² que está en `$r.squared`.
4. `sapply()` se encarga de organizar el output en un vector.
5. El `warning()` es porque estoy regresando mpg en mpg.

Va un ejemplo con `mtcars`.

```
sapply(mtcars, function(x) summary(lm(mtcars$mpg~x))$r.squared) 

      mpg       cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec        vs        am      gear      carb 
1.0000000 0.7261800 0.7183433 0.6024373 0.4639952 0.7528328 0.1752963 0.4409477 0.3597989 0.2306734 0.3035184 
Warning message:
  In summary.lm(lm(mtcars$mpg ~ x)) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

Se podría hacer con un bucle, pero en la mayoría de los casos es mejor algún `*apply()`.